# Dual norm and angle: Does $\arccos \frac{u^T v}{\|u\|\|v\|_*}$ have a name?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\|\cdot\|_*$ be its dual norm. For any nonzero vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define 
\begin{equation}
A(u,v) = \arccos \frac{u^T v}{\|u\|\|v\|_*}. 
\end{equation}
**Question**: Does $A(u,v)$ have a name? Any reference will be highly appreciated.

**Extended question**: Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space, and $(X^*, \|\cdot\|_*)$ be its dual space. For any nonzero vectors $x\in X$ and $x^* \in X^*$, define 
\begin{equation}
A(x,x^*) = \arccos \frac{x^*(x)}{\|x\|\|x^*\|_*}. 
\end{equation}
Does $A(x,x^*)$ have a name?

**Remark**: The original question is indeed a special case of the extended one. Consider the Banach space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|)$. Let $((\mathbb{R}^n)^*, \|\cdot\|_D)$ denote its dual. For each $x^* \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, there exists a unique vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, denoted by $\tau(x^*)$, such that 
\begin{equation}
x^*(x) = x^T \tau(x^*). 
\end{equation}
$\tau$ is a linear bijection between $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. In addition, $\tau: ((\mathbb{R}^n)^*, \|\cdot\|_D) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_*)$ is an isometry, because
\begin{equation}
\|x^*\|_D = \sup_{0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{x^*(x)}{\|x\|} =\sup_{0\neq x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{x^T \tau(x^*)}{\|x\|} =\|\tau(x^*)\|_*.
\end{equation}
Thus $\tau$ is an isometric isomorphism between $((\mathbb{R}^n)^*, \|\cdot\|_D)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_*)$. 
Under this isomorphism, the original question can be regarded as a special case of the extended one.

**Background** (well, this information is not useful for answering the question, but I do not want this question to be marked as "off-topic" for lack of background information): I am a computational mathematician writing a paper on the convergence analysis of a numerical scheme. The quantity $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ arises naturally in my analysis. **$A(\cdot,\cdot)$ is obviously a generalization of the angle in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but it would be nice if this quantity has a commonly accepted name.**

Thank you very much!

Comment: The angle between $u$ and $v$

Comment: The extended question makes sense to me, but the original one does not. You are working with the dual vector to $v$ under some identification of $\Bbb R^n$ and its dual, but you're working with the "regular" $v$ at the same time. I don't see why this is an invariant notion.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean by "invariant". Since you accept that the extended question is reasonable, I edited my post to show that the original question is indeed a special case of the extended one. Thanks again!

Comment: @reuns Thank you! However, it is not the classical angle. In some sense, $u$ and $v$ even lie in different spaces.